# Azure machine learning could not import package azureml-dataprep

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to go through the following tutorial published [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-train-tensorflow) but get the error below when I run these lines fo code:

```
run = exp.submit(est)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

ERROR:

```
"message": "Could not import package \"azureml-dataprep\". Please ensure it is installed by running: pip install \"azureml-dataprep[fuse,pandas]\""
```

However, I have already installed the required packages:

[image]

I am running this through Jupyter Notebooks in an Anacoda Python 3.7 environment.

**UPDATE**

Tried creating a new conda environment as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/resource-known-issues) but still get the same error.

```
conda create -n aml python=3.7.3
```

After installing all the required packages, I am able to reproduce the exeception by executing the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for this. Take a look at the Jupyter Notebook version of the same tutorial:
https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/ml-frameworks/tensorflow/deployment/train-hyperparameter-tune-deploy-with-tensorflow/train-hyperparameter-tune-deploy-with-tensorflow.ipynb

When configuring estimator, you need to specify the pip packages u wanna install on the remote compute. In this case, azureml-dataprep[fuse, blob]. Installing the package to your local computer is not useful since the training script is executed on the remote compute target, which doesn't have the required package installed yet.

```
est = TensorFlow(source_directory=script_folder,
             script_params=script_params,
             compute_target=compute_target,
             entry_script='tf_mnist.py',
             use_gpu=True,
             pip_packages=['azureml-dataprep[pandas,fuse]'])
```

Can you pls try the fix and let us know whether it solves your issue :) In the mean time, I will update the public documentation to include pip_packages in estimator config.

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone through the [`known issues and Troubleshooting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/resource-known-issues) page?. It is mentioned as one of the known issue.

**Error message: ERROR: No matching distribution found for azureml-dataprep-native**

> Anaconda's Python 3.7.4 distribution has a bug that breaks azureml-sdk
>   install. This issue is discussed in this GitHub Issue This can be
>   worked around by creating a new Conda Environment using this command:

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I just created a new environment suggested by link you posted. Unfortunately that did not work either. I will update my post with the details.